# In Flutter, what should I supply to the tag of Hero?

Tags: flutter, random, uuid, hero

I often get errors about "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree."

For now, I have supplied the tag with `Uuid().v4()`. I'm pretty sure that this will be completely random. But I still got these errors.

```
Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
  tag: f63e9e14-55e4-4655-ab96-18b8dbbff524
  state: _HeroState#dc119
```

How can I generate something that will be completely random every time it's called? Or did I use this `Hero` widget incorrectly?

```
FullScreenWidget(child: Hero(child: image(fit: fit), tag: Uuid().v4()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide one unique id for both hero widgets. F.e.

On first screen

```
Screen1(child: Hero(child: image(fit: fit), tag: "Hero1tag"));
```

On second screen:

```
Screen2(child: Hero(child: image(fit: fit), tag: "Hero1tag"));
```

Tag must be unique and stable for all time your app work.

Comment: In my use case, I'm using `FullScreenWidget`. It controls the fullscreen zooming of the image. I don't see anywhere else where I should supply the second tag. I only can supply it once. The thing is, if the image with Hero in a page is only one, it works properly. But once I have two or more image with Hero, it stops working properly.

Comment: Another way: Hero(tag: UniqueKey(), child: Text("123")),
Hero(tag: UniqueKey(), child: Text("456")),
Hero(tag: UniqueKey(), child: Text("987")),
Hero(tag: UniqueKey(), child: Text("721")),

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be unique every time it's called, it needs to be unique per route. In total there should be two of them, one as source hero tag and other as destination hero tag. You can use something descriptive like `'user-profile-picture'`. Keep in mind that the tag could be any other object, like a `UserModel` or something like that.

Comment: When I use `FullScreenWidget`, I don't see where I can put the tag the second time. My entire code to let user tap the image and display full screen is just consist of `FullScreenWidget`, `Button`, `Hero`, and `Image`.

Comment: You can't use Hero without the destination and that destination has to be in a other route, it can't be on the same page. Also, you can use Hero when showing a dialog or bottom sheet.